# How can I reference a GameScene.swift file as a base for the rest of my game levels?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

I'm working on a spritekit game and have the first level complete. For level 1 I used an .sks file to lay out the scene and linked that to a GameScene.swift file for the logic.

When I make my next level, most likely called "GameScene2.swift" Is there a way I can reference the completed Gamescene.swift file as a base for my next levels and then override as necessary? Things like the didMoveto and didBegin are going to be mostly the same between levels.

I've been googling this concept but haven't been able to find much on it, I'm not really sure what to actually call this concept which is probably why I can't find much on it. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can subclass your original Gamescene and inherit all of its functionality from the other game scenes you are creating.

So you would create an original game scene that inherits from SKScene, like this:

```
class OriginalGameScene: SKScene {

    // all of your shared logic here (didMoveTo and didBegin) functions

}
```

And for all the game scenes in your project, just inherit from that original game scene like this:

```
class FirstGameScene: OriginalGameScene {

    // this class has the logic from the functions didMoveTo and didBegin 

}
```

Only put the logic that you want shared throughout every other game scene in your `OriginalGameScene` and you will be able to access any functions or logic that you implement in that `OriginalGameScene` file.

Comment: Would I be able to append to functions in this way? like for instance, the generic didBegin is passed to every level. What if in level two I needed to add a new contact parameter but keep all of the old ones?

Comment: @genericguy25 You can override any functions in the OriginalGameScene if you need to edit their functionality, but adding a new parameter to a function would require you to create an entirely new function.

Comment: ah ok, thank you very much. this seems like the easiest solution!

Answer (score 1):

I handle this a little bit differently.

I put all the core game engine stuff in my GameScene.swift and GameScene.sks files (ie. gameHUD, player, scoring, pause...etc)

I then create my level files separately as Level1.sks, Level2.sks etc. But these will be of class type Level, and this way you don't have to keep repeating generic stuff that is common on all levels in each Level.sks file.
I then load the GameScene file and handle any objects that are generic to all levels.

Then I load up my Level. It is important to note that when doing it like this and having separate sks files for Levels and GameScene you have to move the objects from the Level file to your GameScene when loading them. 
func createLevel(levelID: Int) {

```
if let levelNode = SKReferenceNode(fileNamed: "Level\(levelID)") {

    if let background = levelNode.childNode(withName: "backgroundTiles") as? SKTileMapNode {
        background.move(toParent: self)
    }

    if let water = levelNode.childNode(withName: "waterTiles") as? SKTileMapNode {
        water.move(toParent: self)
    }

    if let badGuy = levelNode.childNode(withName: "badGuy") as? SKSpriteNode {
        self.badGuy = badGuy
        badGuy.move(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

}

> Edit new explanation

Imagine you creating a pacman game.

figure out what would be common to any level. In this case...
 - pacman
 - score label
 - tabulating score
 - ghost movement
 - pacman's movement
 - fruit movement

next figure out what is unique to each level
 - ghost starting location
 - maze
 - fruit start location

So in your GameScene.sks file layout your score labels and any GUI that happens on every level

In your GameScene.swift file handle setting up of any GUI that you laid out in your sks file. Also handle movement of ghosts, movement of pacman, movement of fruit, score handling, physics etc.

Create your mazes in individual SKS files Level1, Level2 etc. What this allows you to do is layout each maze as you want graphically, you can also place your ghost starting locations per level, as well place fruit starting locations per level.

Inside of GameScene you load the level.sks file based on which level the playe r is on. When you load the sks file, you now place your ghosts, level physics, fruit etc based on information loaded from level.sks file.

So now you have a nice stream lined GameScene file that handles all the core functionalitym and nothing is duplicated, and all level specific info is stored in your Level.sks files.

Comment: thanks for a responding! I'm not quite grasping it entirely though, if you would could you please go into a little more on how you setup the actual level class to work with the different level.sks's?

Comment: added some more explanation

Comment: ahh that makes more sense, thank you very much! I'll try this out